# Unable to use the camera properly

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a problem using the camera. . .
whenever I use the camera and try to zoom in or out the light using the camera tools or use another camera setting before taking the photo,
so the photo and the triggered should go back to Application with the image of the photo, but the Application restarts.

If you don't use the zoom, and just open the camera and take the picture, the app works normally.
But this error of the app restarting is kind of random.
I debugged Android Studio, and got the following error:

2020-11-24 17: 51: 39.483 6250-6250 /? I / barcadero.Mone: Late-enabling -Xcheck: jni
2020-11-24 17: 51: 39.530 6250-6250 /? E / barcadero.Mone: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-11-24 17: 51: 40.309 6250-6250 / com.embarcadero.Money W / ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@f9bc15c
2020-11-24 17: 51: 41.440 6250-6250 / com.embarcadero.Money I / AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build: 961b24f, Ib57168459a
Build Date: 02/24/20
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.06
Branch Location:
Remote Branch:
Remote Branch:
Reconstruct Branch:
2020-11-24 17: 51: 41.440 6250-6250 / com.embarcadero.Money I / AdrenoGLES: Build Config: S L 8.0.12 AArch32
2020-11-24 17: 51: 41.490 6250-6250 / com.embarcadero.Money I / AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2020-11-24 17: 51: 41.559 6250-6265 / com.embarcadero.Money W / System: A resource failed to call close.
2020-11-24 17: 51: 41.560 6250-6265 / com.embarcadero.Money W / System: A resource failed to call release.
2020-11-24 17: 51: 42.343 6250-6250 / com.embarcadero.Money W / Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported

Unfortunately I cannot solve this problem. . .

I tried API 28 and API 29, Delphi 10.3.3 and Delphi 10.4.1. The error continues. . .. I count on your help ... thanks

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Comment: "whenever I use the camera and try to zoom in or out the light using the camera tools or use another camera setting before taking the photo, so the photo and the triggered should go back to Application with the image of the photo, but the Application restarts." Sorry but that sentence is beyond my English skills. Could you break it down into shorter sentences?

Comment: Are you using the camera directly in your app or are you "requesting to take a photo" and let the OS handle it for you? if it is the latter, you might have a problem with the fact, that your app can get send to the background by Android and reopened when the "take photo" action returns.